# Fail-Fast apache camel unit test

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

Is it possible to create a "fail fast" unit test for apache camel?

I'm using MockEndpoint in camel unit tests, provide some expectations like message count. And do a call to assertIsSatisfied.

This waits until success or timeout, so if an exchange fails, my test waits for timeout extending the duration. For most tests it's true that a failed exchange means the test will fail. It would be nice that it fails fast - after throwing the exception and not waiting for timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it would not be easy to do via the mock endpoint, however it can be a good improvement, to allow to setup a fail fast mode.

You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket at Apache Camel: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL

You can use the `NotifyBuilder` to setup that when any failed, and then have it trigger, but it won't blend-in well with `assertIsSatisfied` on the mock endpoints.

Comment: Thank you! Created JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12003

Comment: This is no longer true, since the feature has been implemented. It is available since 3.0.0.M5

Comment: And how to do it?